# Logical disjunction with sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have a question involving sets and logical disjunction, I have no idea of how to go about solving it. The question:

A survey of 40 IT users established that:

- All of them used at least one of Word, Excel, Access
- 34 used Word or Access
- 38 used Word or Excel
- 30 used Word
- 26 used Excel
- 17 used Access
- 10 used all three packages

With reference to a Venn diagram, or otherwise, calculate the number of IT users in the survey who:

- Used only Excel
- Used only Access
- ...

Answer (score 1):

Some hints for the first part. Let $U$ be the set of 40 users, and $n \geq 1$:

- All of them used at least one of $S_1$ or $\cdots$ or $S_n$:

$$U \subseteq (\bigcup_{i = 1}^{n} S_i).$$

- $k$ used $S_1$ or $\cdots$ or $S_n$:

$$|U \cap (\bigcup_{i = 1}^{n} S_i)| = k.$$

1. $k$ used all of $S_1$ and $\cdots$ and $S_n$:

$$|U \cap (\bigcap_{i = 1}^{n} S_i)| = k.$$

Answer (score 1):

Out of 40, 38 used Word or Excel, so Access only: $40-38 = 2$.
Out of 40, 34 used Word or Access so Excel only: $40-34 = 6$.
30 used Word and 26 Excel ,total $56 -38 = 18$ (i.e. Word and Excel).
30 used Word and 17 Access, total $47 -34 = 13$ (i.e. Word and Access).
As we already know 10 used all 3 so deduct ($18-10=8$) and ($13-10=3$).